# How to Return Specific Values from a Filter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I have an object array

```
animals[
 {id:1, name:"cat"}, 
 {id:2, name:"dog"}, 
 {id:3, name:"fish"}
]
```

and i have another

```
selected = [1,2]
```

I want to have a return as a string of selected ones:

```
"cat, dog"
```

I currently know how to filter

```
   const selectedAnimals = selected.filter(function(e) {
      return animals.find(o => o.id == e);
    })
```

But this returns the list of ids. How would I rerturn the list of names and in string format? Would I need to use reduce or can i do it with the filter option?

Comment: Just filter the other way round, to find the animals that are selected, then get their names?

Comment: Why do you use filter at all? Will selected ever contain IDs that are not in animals?

Comment: oh crud, yeah that totally slipped me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your `animals` array. Can use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if array contains given value.

```
var selectedAnimals = animals.filter(animal => selected.includes(animal.id));
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var animals = [
 {id:1, name:"cat"}, 
 {id:2, name:"dog"}, 
 {id:3, name:"fish"}
];

var selected = [1,2];

var selectedAnimals = animals.filter(animal => selected.includes(animal.id));

console.log(selectedAnimals);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the filter function backwards.  You should use filter on the `animals` array. Try this:

```
const selectedAnimals = animals.filter(function(e) {
   return selected.find(id => e.id == id);
})
```

This will give you a list of animal objects with ids, then you can loop over that and extract the name if you want to create an array of just the names.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive that by doing the following

```
let animals = [
 {id:1, name:"cat"}, 
 {id:2, name:"dog"}, 
 {id:3, name:"fish"}
]

let selected = [1,2]

const selectedAnimals = animals.filter(e =>(
      selected.includes(e.id))
    )
```

and selectedAnimals should have [ {id: 1, name: "cat"}, {id: 2, name: "dog"} ]

Alternatively, you can use a map but then you will end up with the following.

```
let selectedAnimals = animals.map((e,t) => { if(selected.includes(e.id)) return e.name; else return null} )
```

["cat", "dog", null]